# Update combo depending on previous combo information

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

I have this two tables.

| id | city |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bogota |
| 2 | tunja |

| id | branch | cityid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sector1 | 1 |
| 2 | sector2 | 2 |
| 3 | sector3 | 2 |
| 4 | sector4 | 1 |

now i need to create a way in which the **branch** select field updates depending on the foreign key of the **city**

example:
my first combo should contain city **bogota** and the next combo should only show me the list of branches that are part of that particular city.

how to begin?

Comment: Select * from tableName where cityid = id

Comment: i know how that works in mysql, i need to know how to populate the <select> options based on that request @Dlk